# How to send spread operator to hitComponent in react-redux Algolia?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, algolia, redux-saga

```
Hits hitComponent={Hit} {...this.props} />
```

in above line, *hitComponent* is 'Hit' and **{...this.props}** is set as a props of , but I want it to be at *hitComponent*.

*Hit is a separate class and it is imported to the file where the above code is located.*